# Is the EC50 of an activating protein for an enzyme a good indicator for the binding affinity Kd?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, biophysics

We work with a membrane protein system where measuring the affinity between the enzyme and the upstream activating protein has been difficult, and when measured in detergent solution, it is almost 100 fold lesser (ie ~100nM) whereas the EC50 in an enzymatic assay using vesicles in ~1-2nM. Would it be reasonable to say that the "real" affinity is ~1nM than 100s of nM based on the biochemical assay?

Alternately, is there a documented system where a huge discrepancy exists between measurements from direct binding and biochemical assays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can certainly get massive differences between EC<sub>50</sub> and affinity. This is especially true for cell-based assays and membrane protein systems.

The reason why is because the appropriate time scales to achieve binding equilibrium (hrs for nM affinity, days for picomolar, feptomolar affinity according to back of the envelope calculations) may be and likely will be different from the appropriate time scales of activation, endocytosis, degradation, etc. Furthermore, you can have avidity effects that would not be apparent in a dilute membrane assay compared to a cell's surface. It could very much be that the dominant terms in mass transport change depending on the geometry and antigen density and while I'm not entirely sure bout vesicles vs. emulsions it is true for cancer models. [Theoretical analysis of antibody targeting of tumor spheroids: importance of dosage for penetration, and affinity for retention.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12649189)

**Case study number I:** hGH:hGHR interactions have been extensively studied and high affinity hGH have been produced. However, none of the variants showed improved EC<sub>50</sub>. It turns out that the binding was primarily influenced by the off-rates which were so slow, that affecting those values did little to the kinetics of the system. [Growth Hormone Binding Affinity for Its Receptor Surpasses the Requirements for Cellular Activity](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi9817008)

**Case study number II:** CEA-antibodies have been affinity matured to have pM activity compared to the wild-type nM affinity. However, the antibody had minimal effect on tumor uptake. As CEA gets endocytosed on the order of 30 minutes, all of the antibody was simply getting endocytosed rather than acting as an inhibitor. [Directed evolution of an anti-carcinoembryonic antigen scFv with a 4-day monovalent dissociation half-time at 37°C](http://peds.oxfordjournals.org/content/17/4/293.abstract).

(edit)
I realized that this answer is more applicable to IC<sub>50</sub>s vs. the EC<sub>50</sub> experiments described above. However, many of the points remains. The Km between a substrate and its enzyme is a thermodynamic property where as the EC<sub>50</sub> also has dynamic factors that may influence its measurement.

I would also add that simply adjusting the pH 2 units may result in a 2 orders of magnitude change in activity.

(edit2)
A further point to make about enzymatic assays is that from an observation of Michaelis-Menten kinetics, the K<sub>M</sub> of the reaction isn't the K<sub>D</sub> of the enzyme but alternatively the effective binding constant.

Recall that:

[image]

If there is a non-trivial k<sub>cat</sub> comparable to the dissociation rate k<sub>r</sub>, the enzyme will have an effective half maximal concentration that is significantly higher than the K<sub>d</sub>. There are multiple ways how your assay can result in the discrepancies that you're seeing. The first would your strategy in measuring your EC<sub>50</sub>. If one is an enzymatic readout and the other is a binding readout, you would naturally have very different results.  Alternatively, the enzyme in the detergent system may be catalytically more active than the vesicle system resulting in a higher effective K<sub>M</sub>. Again, the pH thing.

Finally, there is always that awkward moment when you realized that you might accidentally have measured a titration curve rather than a binding curve.

Comment: bobthejoe: I like the detail in your answer, especially the hGH example is very surprising. However, my question pertains to comparing affinities and EC50 measurements, both being derived from in vitro assays with purified proteins. I would think the avidity argument might hold, especially when the same system were compared in a vesicular environment versus detergent solution.

Comment: bobthejoe, just thought I'd say this: You've laid out really well why interpreting Km is not always trivial. Exactly why I chose to focus on EC50 (with the trivial(?) assumption that substrate far exceeds enzyme concentration). I'm going to accept your answer, given the richness of detail that you've laid out!

Answer (score 7):

In what follows I am going to attempt to answer your question using a specific example of  (competitive) reversible activation, and I hope to show what a misleading parameter EC<sub>50</sub> can be.  (Rate law derivation is an area of interest, hence the long-winded answer).

It *can* of course give information, but IMO it needs to be used with extreme care.

I am restricting my comments to the case where A is a *reversible* activator and where  [A] >> e<sub>o</sub> and [S] >> e<sub>o</sub>.  (All constants are defined below).

In short, I am not treating irreversible activation, and I am not treating the case where A is considered a tight-binding activator (so that [A] ≈ e<sub>o</sub>). In other words, I am making the steady-state approximation ([Briggs & Haldane](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1259181/), 1925)

Consider the following simple mechanism for activation in a single-substrate enzyme:

**A Mechanism for Competitive, Reversible Activation**

[image: Competitive Activation DIAGRAM]

The substrate (S) cannot bind to the free enzyme (E) unless the activator (A) is present.  That is, only the activator can bind (reversibly) to E, and the substrate binds (reversibly) to the EA complex.  Reaction occurs within the EAS complex (giving EAP). Dissociation of product (P) from EAP gives EA.

The (steady-state) **initial-rate law** for the above mechanism is the following:

[image: Basic Rate law in three parts eqn1]

As stated, all constants are defined below and follow the usual definitions in enzyme kinetics.  I'll mention just one here: *K<sub>A</sub>* is the *dissociation constant* for the activator, and has units of concentration.

I derived these equations using a computerized version of the King & Altman method ([King & Altman](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j150544a010), 1956), but it is *not* difficult to do. It was pure laziness that prevented a 'first principles' derivation. Rate law derivation is treated in depth in most books on enzyme kinetics and good accounts may be found in Segel (1975) and Cornish-Bowden (2004).

One can now make the following points

- There is no activity without A (as one would expect).
- When [A]  >>  *K*<sub>A</sub>, the rate law becomes identical with the Michaelis-Menten equation (as one would expect).
- The equation is similar to the case of **competitive inhibition**, but (note subtle change) with (1 + *K<sub>A</sub>* / [A]) substituted for (1 + [I] / *K<sub>i</sub>*)
- One can consider this mechanism an example of **competitive activation**

Defining

- *ν<sub>i</sub><sup>exc</sup>*     =     the initial velocity when A is in vast *exc*ess [*ie* setting [A] equal to ∞ in eqn (1) ].
- EC<sub>50</sub>    =     the concentration of A that gives *ν<sub>i</sub>* equal to *ν<sub>i</sub><sup>exc</sup>* / 2 (half-maximal activation)

allows the following two equations to be derived:

[image: Ratio of velocities eqn3]

Setting the left-hand side of the above equal to 2, and solving for [A], gives **the following all-important equation**

> [image: EC50 definition eqn3]

**One can now draw the following conclusions**

- When [S] = K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>

  [image: Conclusion1 S equals to Km]

  In words, when the substrate is present at a concentration equal to the Michaelis constant the value of EC<sub>50</sub> is *half* the value of *K<sub>A</sub>*!.
- When [S] >> K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>

  [image: Conclusion 2 S greater than Km]

  When [S] = 10 x K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>, for example, EC<sub>50</sub> is one-tenth the value of *K<sub>A</sub>*, and when  [S] = 100 x K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub> the figure is one-hundreth.
- When [S] << K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>

  [image: Conclusion 3 S less than Km]

Thus, *for a competitive activator*, it is only when [S] << K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>
that EC<sub>50</sub> gives a reasonable estimate of *K<sub>A</sub>*.

The substrate concentration in a 'normal' enzyme assay will probably be equal to or greater than the Michaelis constant (in order to 'see' activity), and thus EC<sub>50</sub> will be an underestimate of *K<sub>A</sub>*.

If the substrate is present at a 'saturating' concentration (say 10 x K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>) then one is in real trouble.

However, this is *not* the only consideration.  As well as being substrate-concentration dependent, the manner in which EC<sub>50</sub> depends on [substrate] *depends on mechanism*.

As briefly discussed below, the competitive activation case is analogous to that of competitive inhibition. However for *uncompetitive inhibition* the *K<sub>i</sub>* (inhibition constant) is only equal to IC<sub>50</sub> (the concentration of inhibitor giving half-maximal inhibition) *at high substrate concentration*! (see [Naqui](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1152414/), 1982). By analogy, one can conclude that the same is true of uncompetitive activation.

It is very difficult to see how EC<sub>50</sub> can be of any practical use, except perhaps when the mechanism of activation is known.  At the very least, conclusions drawn from EC<sub>50</sub> data should otherwise not be considered definitive.

In addition, I have discussed the only the case of a single-substrate reaction.  Two-substrate reactions have the potential for even greater complexity.

---

**Illustrative Example (Competitive Activation)**

Let's take an example, and check some conclusions:

- *k*<sup>f</sup><sub>cat</sub>   =   1000 s<sup>-1</sup>
- e<sub>o</sub>   =   1
- K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>    =   10 *µ*M
- *K*<sub>A</sub>      =   50 *µ*M

It may be calculated that:

- When [S] equals  10 *µ*M (ie when [S] is equal to K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>) and when [A] is 'saturating' (for the sake of argument set equal to ∞) the velocity is 500 *µ*M s<sup>-1</sup> [from eqn (1) ].

  From eqn (2), the concentration of A required to achieve half this value (half maximal activation) is 25 *µ*M (EC<sub>50</sub> equals 25 *µ*M)

  This value can be directly calculated from eqn (3)
- When [S] equals  100 *µ*M (ie [S] equals 10 x K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>) and when [A] is 'saturating' the velocity is now 909 *µ*M s<sup>-1</sup> [from eqn (1) ].

  From eqn (2), the concentration of A required to achieve half this value  is now only ~4.5 *µ*M

  This value can be directly calculated from eqn (3) [EC<sub>50</sub> equals (50 / 11) *µ*M]
- When [S] equals  1 *µ*M (ie [S] equal to one-tenth the Michaelis constant) and when [A] is 'saturating' the velocity is now only ~91 *µ*M s<sup>-1</sup> [from eqn (1) ].

  From eqn (2), the concentration of A required to achieve half this value is ~45.5 *µ*M (now almost equal to *K<sub>A</sub>*)

  This value can be directly calculated from eqn (3) [EC<sub>50</sub> equals (500 / 11) *µ*M]

---

**Reversible Inhibition & IC<sub>50</sub>.  A Brief Comment**

There is nothing much new in any of the above. In the field of enzyme inhibition, the inadequecies of IC<sub>50</sub> (the concentration of inhibitor giving 50% inhibition) and the relationship to the Inhibition constant are well-known  [see, for example,  [Chou](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=Relationships%20between%20inhibition%20Constants%20and%20Fractional%20Inhibition%20in%20Enzyme-Catalyzed%20Reactions) (1974), Segel (1975), [Naqui](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1152414/) (1982) & [Tsou](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=Tsou%20the%20screening%20of%20enzyme%20targeted%20drugs) (1987)], but (it seems to me) often ignored.

The paper of [Naqui](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1152414/) gives a very succinct analysis of the situation and the [pdf](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1152414/) is freely available to all.

Reversible inhibitors may be divided into four classes, depending on the pattern of inhibition: **competitive, uncompetitive, non-competitive** and **'mixed'** (see [Naqui](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1152414/), 1982, and references therein).

In all cases except non-competitive inhibition, *K*<sub>i</sub> ≠ IC<sub>50</sub>, and IC<sub>50</sub> is substrate- dependent.

(Non-competitive inhibition is the 'fluky' one where it just so happens that the catalytic constant and the specificity constant (*k*<sup>f</sup><sub>cat</sub> / K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>) are changed to the same extent or, to put it another way, the slope and intercept of a Lineweaver-Burk plot (it just so happens) are changed to the same extent)

For an uncompetitive inhibitor (as stated) the IC<sub>50</sub> only equals *K*<sub>i</sub> *at high substrate concentration* (see [Naqui](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1152414/), 1982).

Like the case of competitive activation, IC<sub>50</sub>  equals *K*<sub>i</sub> for a competitive inhibitor only at low susbstrate concentrations (see [Naqui](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1152414/), 1982).

'Mixed' inhibition is even more complex, and the inhibition constant may be greater than or less than IC<sub>50</sub> depending on experimental conditons (see [Naqui](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1152414/), 1982).

Great question, BTW.

---

**Addendum**

As I have derived the full form of the rate law (as opposed to the initial-rate law), it is probably worth posting it. The initial-rate law is obtained from this equation by setting [P] equal to zero.

[image: Full Rate Law for Competitive Activation Kinetic Constant form]

**Kinetic Constants defined in terms of Rate Contants**

Rate constants are numbered (as subscripts) *from species, to species*, with numbering as in diagram.

Thus the rate constant k<sub>1,2</sub> is that from E (species 1) to EA (species 2).

- *Catalytic Constants*

  [image]

  [image: kcatreverse rate constant form]
- *Michaelis Constants*

  [image: KmS Rate Constant Form]

  [image: KmP Rate Constant Form]
- *Specificity Constants*

  [image: Specificity Constant for S rate constant form]

  [image: Specificity Constant for P rate constant form]
- Activation (Dissociation Constant)

  [image: Ka Rate Constant Form]

---

**Kinetic Constant Definition**

- ν     velocity
- *ν<sub>i</sub>*   the initial velocity
- K<sup>S</sup><sub>m</sub>    the Michaelis Constant for S
- K<sup>P</sup><sub>m</sub>    the Michaelis Constant for P
- *k*<sup>f</sup><sub>cat</sub>   the catalytic constant (in the *f*orward direction)
- *k*<sup>r</sup><sub>cat</sub>   the catalytic constant (in the *r*everse direction)
- *V*<sub>max</sub>    the maximum velocity, equal to *k*<sup>f</sup><sub>cat</sub> *e*<sub>o</sub>
- *e*<sub>o</sub>   the total enzyme concentration

  [image]
- *K*<sub>A</sub>      the dissociation constant for (activator), equal to *k*<sub>2,1</sub> / k<sub>1,2</sub>, with units of concentration (Molarity, say) [rate constants are numbered *from species*, *to species*, numbering as in diagram].
- *ν<sub>i</sub><sup>exc</sup>*    the initial velocity when A is in *exc*ess ([A] = ∞).
- EC<sub>50</sub>   the concencentration of A that gives *ν<sub>i</sub>* equal to *ν<sub>i</sub>exc* / 2 (half-maximal activation)
- [A]     The *initial* concentration of activator.
- [S]     The *initial* concentration of substrate.

---

The rate law and the diagrams were obtained using [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/).  For Matematica at SE see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions)

---

**References**

- Briggs, G. E. & Haldane, J. B. S. (1925). A note on the kinetics of enzyme action.  *Biochem. J*. **19**, 338 - 339.[[pdf](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1259181/)]
- Chou, T.C. (1974) Relationships between inhibition constants and fractional inhibition in enzyme-catalyzed reactions with different numbers of reactants, different reaction mechanisms, and different types and mechanisms of inhibition. *Mol. Pharmacol*., **10**, 235-247 [[pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=Relationships%20between%20inhibition%20Constants%20and%20Fractional%20Inhibition%20in%20Enzyme-Catalyzed%20Reactions)]
- Cornish-Bowden, A. (2004). Fundamentals of Enzyme Kinetics. 3rd edn. Portland Press Ltd, London.
- King, E. L. & Altman, C. (1956). A schematic method of deriving the rate laws for enzyme-catalyzed reactions.  *J. Phys. Chem*. **60**, 1375 - 1378. [[ACS site](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j150544a010)]
- Naqui, A. (1982). What does I50 mean? (1983)  *Biochem. J*.  **215**,  429-430 [[pdf](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1152414/)]
- Segel, I. H. (1975). Enzyme Kinetics.  Behavior and Analysis of Rapid Equilibrium and Steady-State Enzyme Systems. John Wiley & Sons, Inc., New York.
- Tsou, C. L. (1987) The screening of enzyme-targeted drugs.  *Bioessays*, **6**, 237-238. [[pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=Tsou%20the%20screening%20of%20enzyme%20targeted%20drugs)]