# $S_{0.5}$ vs $K_m$ values in enzyme kinetics

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, kinetics

What is the difference between $S_{0.5}$ values and $K_m$ values in enzyme kinetics?

Comment: What do you mean by S0.5? $K_M$ is the concentration of substrate at the point when the rate of the reaction is 0.5 of the maximal rate ($V_{max}$).

Comment: I edited the Mathjax into the title as well, as it seems to yield an appropriate URL slug: `http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/s-0-5-vs-k-m-values-in-enzyme-kinetics`

Comment: Km applies to a data set exhibiting MM kinetics, i.e. it has a "mathematical" underpinning. Presumably S0.5 is simply the observed substrate concentration for 0.5 x Vmax regardless of whether the data fit MM?

Comment: probably worth looking at http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/is-the-ec50-of-an-activating-protein-for-an-enzyme-a-good-indicator-for-the-bind

Answer (score 2):

This expands my comment on the question to an answer.

If an enzyme exhibits Michaelis-Menten kinetics, then it is valid to define a K<sub>M</sub> and this equates to the substrate concentration when reaction velocity is 0.5 * V<sub>max</sub>.

However, many enzymes do not exhibit Michaelis-Menten kinetics. One example is when the enzyme shows a co-operative response to substrate concentration. In these circumstances the substrate concentration when reaction velocity is 0.5 * V<sub>max</sub> is still a useful parameter, but there is no K<sub>M</sub>.

See [this paper](http://diabetes.diabetesjournals.org/content/47/3/307.full.pdf) for a discussion of the kinetic properties of the glucokinase of pancreatic β cells, which acts as the glucose sensor. This enzyme shows positive co-operativity with respect to its substrate glucose, and the authors develop a kinetic analysis in terms of various parameters. These include an S<sub>0.5</sub> value for glucose, but a K<sub>M</sub> value for ATP (presumably because the kinetics with respect to ATP are simple Michaelis-Menten).