# Ligand-binding assays: IC50, EC50 and Kd

Tags: biochemistry, protein-binding

I am reviewing several MHC-peptide binding affinity predictors trained on  [IEDB](https://www.iedb.org) data. Quantitative records for MHC class I allotypes come from a lot of different assays and, by extension, have different measurement types. Here are the most common measurement type descriptions (I haven't altered them in any way):

1. dissociation constant KD (~IC50)
2. dissociation constant KD (~EC50)
3. half maximal inhibitory concentration (IC50)
4. dissociation constant KD
5. half maximal effective concentration (EC50)

All of the predictors I've reviewed so far consider these measurement types interchangeable, which I find extremely odd. While IC50 and EC50 can indeed be similar under certain experimental circumstances, I find it hard to believe that any one of these can be approximately equal to Kd (this site already has a [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/is-the-ec50-of-an-activating-protein-for-an-enzyme-a-good-indicator-for-the-bind) on this matter). I've contacted several authors and database curators, and all of them have assured me that these values can indeed be considered more-or-less interchangeable, but I can't find any references to support these claims.

Comment: Not an answer (I can’t comment yet), but what is the difference between 1, 2, and 4?

Comment: @MarkusHeller as far as I understand, 4 means either 1 or 2.